# Is there an equivalent of jQuery infinite drag for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zui

I am trying to create an app that will have an infinite wall interface, i.e., a div that opens onto a background that the user can drag around and that will expand forever wherever the user goes.

I found a cool jquery plugin called [jquery infinite drag](https://ianli.github.io/jquery-infinite-drag/) to do this, but I am having trouble using it with react. Is there a library with a component like this?

Comment: You might look at `react-window`. Its pretty low level and you will have to implement the drag scrolling yourself, but it is highly optimized for large/infinite data views.

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite?